# Why didn't the mutants in the Danger Room use weapons?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Is there a reason that mutants won't or can't use weapons in the Danger Room? Does it have something to do with the professor being peace-loving or that they are kids or that they have to train with their powers? I know different states have different regulations but I'm pretty sure there has got to be some weapons they could use.

I can only think of one mutant that uses a weapon and that is Gambit (staff) and he was trained by thieves so is there a reason why the X-Men didn't use weapons?

Comment: Longshot uses to throw small knives, Psylocke used a katana quite usually, Magick used a soul sword and a soul armor, Cable was a full armory on foot, Nightcrawler loved to fence with sabers (2 or even 3!) when he has an opportunity.. and the list goes so on...

Comment: Don't Bishop and Cable use weapons?

Comment: I've edited this fairly heavily to focus on your question about the 'Danger Room' in X-Men: The Last Stand. If you want to re-ask the question about X-Men using weapons (in general), that might make a good second question.

Comment: In other incarnations (comics and tv shows), they *do* use weapons, often damaging the room and the equipment. I believe it was one of the 90's show episodes where Xavier told Wolverine that he couldn't afford to let the training session run any longer due to how much damage was being done.

Answer (score 2):

With regard to the Danger room exercise in X-Men: The Last Stand it's important to note that the simulation was intended to be a "run and hide" exercise, not an offensive operation. Even if we ignore the potential risk of the kids killing themselves and others around them with friendly fire, the simple fact is that they were supposed to be *evading* the enemy, not engaging them:

> **Storm:** It was a defensive exercise.
>
> **Logan:** Yeah, best defense is a good offence.
>
> <sub><sup>[X-Men Last Stand - Transcript](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=x-men-the-last-stand)</sup></sub>

and

> Backed into a rhetorical corner, he said nothing.
>
> “If you’d read the syllabus, you’d know this was a defensive exercise.
> Evasive maneuvers.”
>
> <sub><sup>[X-Men: The Last Stand - Official Novelisation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345492110)</sup></sub>

It's also worth pointing out that metal weapons can be fairly easily turned against you by someone who can control metal.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! This gives me more questions but you answered my first question. (I was suppose to ask just one and it does say no list but weapon carrying mutant doesn't sound so broad right?). Thanks so much for answering so quickly.